# How can I remove the left-margin of the glossaries "long" style?

Tags: spacing, glossaries

How can I remove the spacing (marked red) produced by the `long` style by `glossaries`? I wasn't able to find information on customizing the style in the package documentation.

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[nogroupskip,nonumberlist,nopostdot]{glossaries}
\setglossarystyle{long}
\makenoidxglossaries
\newacronym{pt}{pt}{point}
\newacronym{pc}{pc}{pica}
\newacronym{mu}{mu}{math unit}
\begin{document}
\printnoidxglossary
\chapter{Introduction}
Spacing can be expressed in \gls{pt}, \gls{pc} or \gls{mu}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You (I) can use `longtable` settings. Just add `\setlength\LTleft{0mm}`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[nogroupskip,nonumberlist,nopostdot]{glossaries}
\setglossarystyle{long}
\setlength\LTleft{-\tabcolsep}
\makenoidxglossaries
\newacronym{pt}{pt}{point}
\newacronym{pc}{pc}{pica}
\newacronym{mu}{mu}{math unit}
\begin{document}
\printnoidxglossary
\chapter{Introduction}
Spacing can be expressed in \gls{pt}, \gls{pc} or \gls{mu}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: This will affect *all* `{longtable}`s in your document. It would be better to redefine `\LTleft` in a group when calling `\printnoidxglossary`. Also `\setlength\LTleft{-\tabcolsep}` might be closer to what you expect.

Comment: @campa Thank you! I was still digging around trying to figure out where those last pixels of spacing came from.